# How to compile a list of numbers in parentheses with Regex with Python

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to use Regex to find all the numbers in parentheses, for example, with this input:

```
"PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"
```

I want this:

```
[23, 45, 98, 34, 18]
```

I tried this:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"\((\d+)\)")
final = list(pattern.findall("PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"))
```

And it's only returning empty lists

Comment: I edit the question

Comment: Your pattern matches parentheses containing *only* digits, which isn't what you've shown.

Comment: @jonrsharpe is trying to point out the fact that there are commas and whitespace inside the parenthesis as well...you need to account for these

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a positive lookahead pattern:

```
re.findall(r'\d+(?=[^(]*\))', s)
```

so that given `s = "PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"`, this returns:

```
['23', '45', '98', '34', '18']
```

or if you prefer the list items to be integers, you can map them to `int`:

```
list(map(int, re.findall(r'\d+(?=[^(]*\))', s)))
```

which returns:

```
[23, 45, 98, 34, 18]
```

Comment: What the living hell? How does that regex work? Where have you been when this question was asked before? I'm trying to translate it for myself and am struggling but this is AWESOME!! I'm wondering why 19 and 20 aren't captured and if they'd be captured if the were immediately followed by a comma (`,`)

Comment: Oh wow. Just figured it out. Woahh, that is a whole new level of regex wonkiness. This is great.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know about regex, but you can do without it:

```
string = "PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"
numbers = []

for s in string.split("(")[1].split(","):
    numbers.append(int(s.rstrip(")")))

print(numbers) # [23, 45, 98, 34, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do the following:

```
my_list = list(map(int, re.findall(r'\((.*?)\)', s)[0].split(',')))
```

Yields:

```
[23, 45, 98, 34, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use RegEx, this is one solution:

```
import re
import ast
regex = r" \(( *\d+,*)+\)"

test_str = "PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)
for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print(list(ast.literal_eval(match.group().strip())))
```

And the output is:

```
[23, 45, 98, 34, 18]
```

Answer (score 1):

you may use this code, it is not the shortest way but it is readable:

```
import re
text = "PO = 19 AND TR = 12 AND CD NOT IN (23, 45, 98, 34, 18)"
a = re.search(r'\(.+\)', text).group()
b = re.findall(r'\d+', a)
print(b)
```

output:

```
['23', '45', '98', '34', '18']
```